# "refusing to update ref with bad name" when using `git rebase --rebase-merges`

Tags: git, git-merge, git-rebase

I've recently had to look at `git rebase --rebase-merges`, but I'm not having much luck.

I maintain a fork of the Rust compiler and I've just recently merged in upstream, fixing a ton of merge conflicts along the way. Then I had to do a second merge, as I got unlucky and the upstream repo was busted at the time I did the first merge.

I was hoping to use `git rebase -i --rebase-merges` to squash my two merges together, but preserving the nested merges created upstream (if that's even possible).

The problem is, whatever I try I get this error message:

```
$ git rebase --rebase-merges -i sd-upstream/master                                                                         
error: refusing to update ref with bad name 'refs/rewritten/Auto-merge-of-#65134---davidtwco:issue-19834-improper-ctypes-in-extern-C-fn,-r=rkruppe'
hint: Could not execute the todo command
hint: 
hint:     label Auto-merge-of-#65134---davidtwco:issue-19834-improper-ctypes-in-extern-C-fn,-r=rkruppe
hint: 
hint: It has been rescheduled; To edit the command before continuing, please
hint: edit the todo list first:
hint: 
hint:     git rebase --edit-todo
hint:     git rebase --continue
```

(In the above `sd-upstream` is my organisation's upstream, not Rust's -- I'm rebasing against the tree before my branch with the merges on)

I get the above error **even when I make no changes to the todo**.

Am I doing something wrong, or is that a git bug? Looks like git is choking on the commit message auto-generated by Bors (a bot used by the Rust team to do rollup merges and the like).

I'm using git-2.20.1 on Debian 10.

Comment: Have you tried undoing your first rebase using the reflog, and then rebase the whole thing at once? I have no idea about your actual problem, but there's some chance that it could work

Comment: Do you mean, go back to just after the first merge and then redo the second merge without generating a merge commit and squashing it in?

Comment: I actually meant going back to before the first merge and merge all the new changes in one step. I now realize that that would mean you would have to do your "ton of merge conflicts" again though. And there's no guarantee that that would work, just an idea

Comment: Yeah, trying to avoid doing the merge conflicts again. Even with rerere enabled it's going to be messy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was a bug in `--rebase-merges` that was fixed in Git 2.25:

> - A label used in the todo list that are generated by "git rebase
>     --rebase-merges" is used as a part of a refname; the logic to come
>     up with the label has been tightened to avoid names that cannot be
>     used as such.

Along with that bug was a related one:

> - The logic to avoid duplicate label names generated by "git rebase
>     --rebase-merges" forgot that the machinery itself uses "onto" as a
>     label name, which must be avoided by auto-generated labels, which
>     has been corrected.

(Both of these are from the Git 2.25 [release notes](https://github.com/git/git/blob/d8437c57fa0752716dde2d3747e7c22bf7ce2e41/Documentation/RelNotes/2.25.0.txt#L104-L112).)

If you upgrade your Git to version 2.25, the problem should go away.  Until then, the best advice I have is "don't use `--rebase-merges`".

Comment: Ah! I'll try updating git then! While I am here, will squashing my two merge commits do what I think? Will it make one merge commit, but leave the commits inside both intact?

Comment: I haven't experimented with the new rebase-merges option. I don't know what it will think of squashing two merge commits. My guess is that it would refuse to do that. The only sensible interpretation I can see is to attempt an octopus merge, which should be possible as well, so it might do that.

Comment: Well after fixing up the second merge into the first, I get merge conflicts on files I have not touched, so it's obviously not the right thing! Thanks for your answer, I've marked it as accepted :)

Comment: For those who were in the middle of a really tedious interactive rebase with a lot of conflicts and don't want to give up in the middle to redo everything -- install the update, then `cp` your current working directory with an in-progress rebase.  Then abort the rebase in the copy and issue the same command for the interactive rebase you had before.  When it stops on a conflict do `git rebase --edit-todo` in both directories and copy the labels from the one that a new version of git produced to the old one (original in-progress rebase); save and `git rebase --cont`.  This worked for me.